# Generating emails using blat.exe not working for every domain

Tags: html, email, html-email, blat

I use blat.exe running from Powershell to generate e-mails with HTML. When I'm sending an e-mail to the Google domain everything is OK and code is generating fine. The headers and rest of code look like this:

```
<html xmlns=3D"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3Dutf-8">
<title>My email</title>
</head>
...
<tr style=3D"height:15pt;">
 <td style=3D"border: 1pt solid; border-color:black; padding-left:3.5pt=
; height: 15pt;">
...
```

But when I send the same e-mail to my client's domain, the HTML code look much different:

```
<html xmlns="ttp://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml&quot;"><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>My email</title>
</head>
...
<tr style="eight:15pt;&quot;">
 <td style="order:" 1ptsolid;border-color:black;padding-left:3.5pt;height:15pt;?="">
...
```

Do you have any ideas why in second option first letters after quotes are missing or why quotes at the end of the line are changed to `&quot;"` or `?="`? Spaces in style are missing too.

My blat command looks like this: `./blat.exe 'C:\path\file.html' -f alert@clientsdomain.com -server mail.clients.server.addr -to 'my_email@google.com,other_email@clientsdomain.com' -subject 'email title' -html`

Thanks in advance for any tips!

Answer (score 0):

I found neither the reason nor the exact solution but I have some workaround. 
I used just Powershell with a simple command and it worked:

```
$body= Get-Content "C:\path_to_html_file\file.html" | out-string 
Send-MailMessage -From "alert@clientsdomain.com" -to 'my_email@google.com', 'other_email@clientsdomain.com' -Subject "email title" -Body $body -BodyASHtml -SmtpServer "mail.clients.server.addr" -Encoding ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8)
```